# Problem getting HttpErrorResponse from httpClient

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I got a problem using angular and a .net backend. In my application Im trying to return http status 403 Forbidden when the user tries to do something that is not allowed.

In my backend Controller

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserProject>> DeleteUserProject(int id)
{
    ...
    // Insufficient permissions"
    return Forbid();
}
```

in my angular service

```
deleteProjectUser(userProjectId: number): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.delete(`${environment.apiUrl}/UserProjects/${userProjectId}`, { observe: 'response' })
    .pipe(
      tap(
        userProject => {
          // works
          return userProject;
        },
        error => {
          // Expecting HttpErrorResponse with error.status == 403
          console.log(error);
        }));
}
```

and in my angular component

```
leaveProject(userProjectId: number) {
    console.log('remove user-project with id: ' + userProjectId);
    this.projectService.deleteProjectUser(userProjectId)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          // everything worked
        },
        error => {
          // Expecting propagated HttpErrorResponse
          console.log(error);
        });
}
```

I can see that the backend returns 403 with no body as expected in chrome. But I dont get a HttpErrorResponse from http.delete when the backend returns 403 with the Forbid() method. I get a TypeError.

Output in the chrome console

```
remove user-project with id: 1202
userProjectService.leaveProject userProjectId: 1202
DELETE http://localhost:5000/api/UserProjects/1202 403
TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of null
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (error.interceptor.ts:20)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:29)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:2477)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:465)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1603)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone-evergreen.js:1640)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of null
```

Ok, but if I dont use the Forbid() method. I can set a body so I changed my backend to

```
return new ObjectResult("Forbidden") { StatusCode = 403 };
```

Then I get the string "Forbidden" as error in my service and component. But still no HttpErrorResponse from HttpClient. What is wrong? I want a HttpErrorResponse and the http status code from HttpClient.delete if somethings goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stack trace shows that you have an `error.interceptor` in your application. The `TypeError` occurs in that part of your system. You can check line 20 in your interceptor to see more details about the issue you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thank you! I missed that. The error interceptor throwed a new error. Not the the intercepted one.